# Removing the space at the top of my website

Tags: html, css, margins

I am just getting back into coding after a 4 year hiatus and a lot of things on the web have changed since then. A problem that troubled me then is removing the space from the top of the page. I have tried everything from padding to margins, in my body, table, and div styles.

The web address is http://www.studio1194.com/index1.htm

Comment: "Inspect" it with Firebug http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
 border-collapse: collapse;
```

To the style of the `table` itself.

But you should look into making layouts with css, instead of tables.

Comment: thanks I really appreciate that. I am trying to dive deeper into wrapping my mind around using just css, so for now the tables are really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if using a negative margin is RIGHT but this works:

```
table.main {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 **margin-top: -2px;**
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 800px;
 padding: 0px;
 border-width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add: `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"`
 in table tag

```
<table class="main" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```